# How to send email from the c# program?

Tags: c#

I need to send an email from my program I wrote this code but it did not work the error was

> " Le serveur SMTP requiert une connexion sécurisée ou le client n'était pas authentifié. La réponse du serveur était : 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. e2sm19845644wix.15 - gsmtp "

English Translation:

> "The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated The server response was : 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first e2sm19845644wix.15 - gsmtp"

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {   
         MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
        SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");

         SmtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("oussabdalla@gmail.com", "xxx");
        mail.From = new MailAddress("oussabdalla@gmail.com");
        mail.To.Add(textBox4.Text);
        mail.Subject = "Attention";
        mail.Body = textBox1.Text + textBox2.Text + textBox3.Text + "est absent de " + comboBox5.SelectedValue + "a" + comboBox4.SelectedValue;

        SmtpServer.Port = 587;



        SmtpServer.Send(mail);
        SmtpServer.EnableSsl = true;
        MessageBox.Show("mail Send");

    }
    catch (Exception ex)  
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

I changed my code following recommendations and got a new error

> " Le délai d'attente de l'opération a expiré  "

Translated:

> "The transaction timeout has expired"

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        try
        {
            SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");
            MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
            SmtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("oussabdalla@gmail.com", "xxxxx");
            SmtpServer.UseDefaultCredentials = false;

        mail.From = new MailAddress("oussabdalla@gmail.com");
        mail.To.Add(textBox4.Text);
        mail.Subject = "Attention";
        mail.Body = textBox1.Text + textBox2.Text + textBox3.Text + "est absent de " + comboBox5.SelectedValue + "a" + comboBox4.SelectedValue;

        SmtpServer.Port = 465;

        SmtpServer.EnableSsl = true;

        SmtpServer.Send(mail);

        MessageBox.Show("mail Send");

    }
    catch (Exception ex)  
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Please translate your error message to English.

Comment: Have you authenticated with your credentials it seems you have a problem with Authentication

Comment: The transaction timeout has expired

Answer (score 3):

You need to set `SmtpServer.EnableSsl = true;` before you call `SmtpServer.Send(mail);` in order to be effective.

With my limited knowledge of french, I'd say the message asks you to use a secure connection using STARTTLS.

Google says, when you use the port 587, you need to use TLS, as stated [here](https://support.google.com/a/answer/176600). So maybe you consider using port 465, which indicates usage of SSL instead of the 587-TLS-port.

[Here is another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32260/sending-email-in-net-through-gmail) that explains well along an example how to send emails via gmail. It makes also clear, that you need to set `UseDefaultCredentials = false` before you assign your actual Credentials!

Comment: that's new erreur "Le serveur SMTP requiert une connexion sécurisée ou le client n'était pas authentifié. La réponse du serveur était : 5.5.1 Authentication Required. Learn more at"

Comment: Sorry, my french ends here ^.^ Please translate to English.

Comment: hhhh  yes with pleasure :p

Comment: that's new error "SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated The server response was:.. 5.5.1 Authentication Required Learn more at"

Comment: Remember what I said: Google assumes connections on port 587 to be TLS secured. You want to use SSL, so use 465.

Comment: And please, update the question so other users don't attempt to give the same answer as I did.

Comment: Please see the updates to my answer, including the link. Should be working.

Answer (score 2):

```
try
            {
                MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
                SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");
                mail.From = new MailAddress("fromeamilp@gmail.com");
                mail.To.Add("toemail@gmail.com");
                mail.Subject = "Subject of email...";
                mail.Body = "Body of email...";
                SmtpServer.Port = 587;
                SmtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("gmailusername", "gmailpass");
                SmtpServer.EnableSsl = true;
                SmtpServer.Send(mail);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            }
```